# Mysql - Slow when getting 4 milions record from table that has 60 miliions records

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I'm currently using AWS Aurora Mysql(ServerlessV2).

Engine version: Aurora MySQL 3.04.0 (compatible with MySQL 8.0.28)

I have table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE "Test" (
  "key1" varchar(37) NOT NULL,
  "key2" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "key3" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  "createdDate" timestamp(3) NOT NULL,
  "createdBy" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "updatedDate" timestamp(3) NOT NULL,
  "updatedBy" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("key1","key2","key3")
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

I have simple query that

```
select key3
 FROM Test WHERE key1  = 
 'value1' and key2= 'value2'
```

It took me arround 30-35 seconds to return 4 milion row(s).

```
3934328 row(s) returned
Duration/fecth: 0.141 sec / 34.375 sec
```

About innodb_buffer_pool_size, its about 2Gb

```
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size
--
@@innodb_buffer_pool_size
2471493632
```

I tried to increase innodb_buffer_pool_size to arround 7Gb by increase Serverless v2 capacity settings. But seems no affection. It is still slow.
I want it to be under 5s to get arround 4milions records.
Can you suggest anyway to speed up this query

Comment: *Duration/fecth: 0.141 sec / 34.375 sec* tells that the rows selection takes 141 ms whereas their transferring from server to clien takes 34 sec. So the problem is not in selection but in communication.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how long it takes to get the `COUNT(key3)`, as it should better indicate the time taken to build the full result set. The duration is the time until first row, not the total execution time, as it can start streaming the results before building the full result set.

Comment: Do you really need to retrieve ~4M rows? Are `key1` and `key2` the full 37 and 50 chars (single byte?) respectively? Given the low cardinality of the combined `(key1, key2)`, replacing the string values with TINYINTs would reduce the 87 chars to 2B per row. Similarly for createdBy and updatedBy. Please update your question with the size of your test table (``SELECT ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / POW(1024, 3), 2) AS size_GB FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Test';``) and average length for each of the five varchar columns.

Answer (score 0):

ggever, In your Parameters group, consider this suggestion,

```
net_buffer_length=98304  # from 16384 to reduce packet count sent/received
```

after this change, logoff/logon for the new NBL to be in service and get new timings, please.  Please post Duration information so we all know what this one change does for you.

```
select @@net_buffer_length; to confirm your new size of NBL, please.
```

and check it again in a week to be sure your settings are still in service.

If not let AWS know what you are trying to accomplish, please.

View profile, please.

Answer (score 0):

- Consider normalizing the strings.  (It is unclear whether this will help or add a problem of `JOINs`.)
- `ADD INDEX(key2, key1, key3)` - This will a smaller BTree to search (for *that* query) and will be "covering".  The current query presumably (please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT`) uses the `PRIMARY KEY` but does a range scan of only the desired 4M rows.  This added index will do a similar thing, but there will be less data to fetch from disk.
- Increasing the buffer_pool_size helps if "caching" is useful.  It may be that the query in question is finding all the data in the cache or it may not.  So, I am not surprised that increasing its size did not help *for this case*.
- Is the disk HDD or SSD?  The latter is significantly faster.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not in the speed of the query - that lasts about 140 milliseconds. Your problem is in *getting the results*, i.e. four million values of key3.

For some reason, those (at most) 240 megabytes take 34 seconds to be transferred.

You already have keys 1-3 in a primary key, so indexing will yield no gains.

The best approach would be to reduce the number of values returned:

- do you really need *four million different values* each time?
- are those four million different values? What if you requested `key3, count(*) ... GROUP BY key3`? Or might a `DISTINCT` be enough?

Otherwise, other things might help:

- increasing network buffer width will reduce packets to be sent, but this is unlikely to be a game changer (unless there are very specific network issues).
- key3 already avails itself of a properly clustered index, *but that index might have become fragmented*. Have you tried running an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on your Test?
- do you really need `utf8mb4` collation? For simple textual values, `ascii_bin` sometimes yields better performances.
- while we're talking about collations: for each and every *column value* extracted from the database, if the *connection collation* and the *table collation* do not match, MySQL will have to run a conversion subroutine, *even if that conversion will perform no changes*, because it cannot know beforehand whether it will or won't. In other words, **having a collation mismatch between connection and table will slow you down**.